# Prime number code error 10001's prime (python)

Tags: python, primes

I have made a program to find primes, but when I try to get the 10001st prime it isn't correct. I can't figure out why.

I haven't really tried much because I have no idea what to try.

```
import math
startingPrimes = [2,3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
for times in range (2):
    primeList = []
    numbersToBeTested = 0
    for _ in range (startingPrimes[len(startingPrimes)-1]**2):
        primeList.append(_ + 2)
    print ()
    numbersToBeTested = startingPrimes[len(startingPrimes)-1]**2
    print (numbersToBeTested)
    divisor = 0
    term = 0
    dividend = 0
    position = 0

    while divisor < math.sqrt(len(primeList)):
        term = 0
        divisor = startingPrimes[position]
        dividend = primeList[position]
        while term + 1 < len(primeList):

            term = term + 1
            if primeList[term] % divisor == 0:
                if primeList[term] != divisor:
                    primeList.remove(primeList[term])
        position = position + 1
    startingPrimes = primeList

for termOfList in range (len(primeList)):
    print (primeList[termOfList])
print ("How many primes: " + str(len(primeList)))
print ("10001st prime: " + str(primeList[10000]))
```

It gives me 90373 which is wrong!
Please help!

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with your code:

It generates primes that *aren't prime*, e.g. 99973 = 257 * 389

It's nearly impossible to figure how it decides when it's found sufficient primes.

It has bizarre expressions that seem to make no sense, eg.:

```
   for times in range (2):
       primeList = []
```

This appears to run the code twice!  But it changes the result!
   Where's the code comment!

And there's this:

```
while divisor < math.sqrt(len(primeList)):
```

The square root of the number of primes you found so far is a limit when searching for your next prime?

Problematic programs tend to be underwritten or overwritten -- this is an example of an overwritten program.  You can solve this problem with a dozen lines of Python, of no more than roughly 30 characters each, in a fraction of a second.  Your program requires more than twice that many lines, some twice that length, and takes nearly a minute to come up short on the answer.

My advice is to start over and keep it simple:

You don't need `startingPrimes = [2,3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]`.  Just initializing `primeList = [2]` is sufficient to avoid testing even numbers and focus on odd divisors.

You don't need `math.sqrt()`, simply test if `if divisor * divisor > number:` and all the divisors you need are in `primeList`.

The only modification operation you really need to do on `primeList` is `append()`.

Somewhere there should be an explicit test for completion, eg.:

```
while len(primeList) < n:  # where n = 10001
```